# How to catch a SMS spammer who is using google voice to spam me

Tags: spam, sms

How do I catch a SMS spammer who is using google voice to spam me?

I have the google voice number and 2 of their burner emails with gmail. How do I gather enough information to inform the authorities?

Comment: The previous version of the question was closed as you were asking for guidance on something that is illegal in many places. This question is much more appropriate, but as @Rook says - get basic information (without committing an offence yourself) and leave it up to google/the authorities.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't play cops and robbers,  just report the issue to Google and they will take care of it.  Google and the authorities have better tools and people who are paid to deal with these criminals.

That being said,  one way to identify someone online via chat or sms is to get them to visit a URL.  This could load a page that logs the IP address, and then you can perform a whois or geoip lookup on this address.  More advanced/blackhat/illegal method would have that URL return a page that exploits a vulnerability in the browser and then you can collect personal information from the spammer's machine.

Comment: It's also worth noting that, depending on your carrier, you may be able to send the message and sender details to a special number (i.e.: "SPAM" or 7726) so they can use it to update their filtering and/or do their own abuse follow-up.

Comment: Where do I report SMS spamming on Google?